# How to extract more data from an ambigious nginx request?

Tags: nginx

My production server has been getting around 6000 unknown requests per second for the past hours and nginx access log is not giving enough data about these requests. I have never seen requests like these in the access logs and I have no idea how to find any more information about these requests. Here is a sample of these requests.

```
5.112.127.138 - - [14/Jun/2018:14:20:48 +0430] "o\xEB\x04Ke\xBA\xF6\x10\xCD\xB4\xAE\x17^\x9B\xFCgLp\xD0L\xBF\xDA\xE8\xE7K\x8C}\x8B\xEFM\xE4\xAF3>\xBDp\xDCy\x90\xCD\x1C\x16a\xEFn\xC6T\xE6\xB1\xF8\x10\x07umn\xA3" 400 173 "-" "-"
5.235.234.134 - - [14/Jun/2018:14:20:48 +0430] "\xA6\xCA#\x89\xFF1\xAE" 400 173 "-" "-"
```

I checked the result of *whois* for a lot of these IPs and most of them are IPs from common ISPs in my country.
Specifically it would be useful if I can find out what was the target address for these requests.

Answer (score 0):

You access log is displaying the default log format. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format) for details.

You can customise the log format by using the `log_format` and/or `access_log` directives within the `http` block of the `nginx` configuration (`nginx.conf`).

For example, to add the value of the `Host` request header ($http_host`), you could use:

```
log_format enhanced
    '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
    '$http_host "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

access_log  /path/to/logfiles/enhanced.log enhanced;
```

Comment: I tried changing the log_format. But `$http_host` or `$host` had no data ("-").